# Properties - by value or reference?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I've got the following public property which exposes an `Arraylist`:

```
public ArrayList SpillageRiskDescriptions
        {
            get
            {
                return _SpillageRiskDescriptions;
            }
            set
            {
                _SpillageRiskDescriptions = value;
            }
        }
```

Elsewhere I'm calling

```
SpillageRiskDescriptions.Add("VENTILATE AREA");
SpillageRiskDescriptions.Add("DO NOT ALLOW SPILLAGE TO ENTER MAINS");
```

These seem to be adding elements to the private ArrayList `_SpillageRiskDescriptions` (through the property) whereas I would've expected this to cause a problem.  Therefore am I correct in thinking that properties return a **reference** to the original variable and not passing it by **value**?  Is this because `ArrayList` is a reference type?  Will the same happen with an `int` (for example?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technically it's always by value, but you have to understand what is being passed.  Since it's a reference type, you are passing a reference back (but by value).

Hope that makes sense.  You always pass the result back by value, but if the type is a reference you are passing the reference back by value, which means you can change the object, but not which object it refers to.

Comment: Think of it like C++, you can pass a pointer to an object, and you can alter what that pointer points to, but you can't make it point to something else because you have a copy of the pointer and not the original pointer.  If you want to change which object it points to, you have to pass a pointer to a pointer (or a reference to a pointer).  This is why in C# you need the ref and out keywords if you want to alter what object is being referred to.

Comment: Excellent - this makes perfect sense

Answer (score 9):

The other answers have correctly answered your primary question: that the *value* of a *property of reference type* is a *reference* to an *instance* of the reference type.

The larger question is "now what do you do about it?" Presumably you do *not* want code that can *obtain* the list to be able to *change* it.

There are several options here.

First, no matter what you do I recommend that you stop using ArrayList right now and start using a more modern, safe type for storing a list of things. `List<string>` comes immediately to mind.

Second, is it necessary that the *setter* of the property be public?  Do you want just anyone to be able to change that list? Or should the type itself be responsible for updating it somehow?  I'd consider making the setter private.

Third, we have a more compact syntax for a "trivial" property. You could be saying

```
public List<string> SpillageListDescriptions { get; private set; }
```

and the compiler will generate the backing field for you.

Note that `List<string>` still allows mutation.

If all the client cares about is being able to iterate over the list one thing at a time, then you can do this:

```
private List<string> descriptions = whatever;
public IEnumerable<string> SpillageListDescriptions 
{ 
    get 
    {
        if (descriptions == null) yield break;
        foreach(var description in descriptions) 
            yield return description;
    }
}
```

and now it is impossible for the caller to mutate the list, because all you're giving them is an iterator over it, not access to the list itself.

Or you could do:

```
private List<string> descriptions = whatever;
public IList<string> SpillageListDescriptions 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(descriptions); 
    }
}
```

And now the caller has a read-only view of the list that will throw an exception if they attempt to modify it.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback however most of these (short property syntax and private setter with public getter) are only available in later versions of the framework - I'm using .NET2.  The whole reason I'm actually visiting this is so that I can convert ArrayList into List<string>.  However its good to find out what I'm doing is right.

Comment: The only solution he mentioned that is not available in .Net 2 is auto-properties, which can trivially implemented in .Net 2 by hand.  You'll also need to replace `var` with `string`.

Answer (score 2):

C# returns objects by reference.

Only things that aren't returned by value are:

Primitive types.
Struct types.
Enums.

Comment: true in essence, though technically it passes back object references by value.

Comment: Also c++ pointers are passed back by value, but that's the definition of by reference. The address of the object is passed instead of the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with whether it is a property per se; it is the data type of the property. In this case, you are using `ArrayList` which is a class that is passed by reference. If the property were typed as an `int` it would be passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

A property is actually a pair of two methods — a setter and a getter. They pass the value of the backing field (or whatever is used as the source / destination) as it is. Hence, for reference types the reference is passed, and for value types the value is passed.

```
// this is how the getter method looks like
public ArrayList get_SpillageRiskDescriptions()
{
    return _SpillageRiskDescriptions;
}

// this is how the setter method looks like
public void set_SpillageRiskDescriptions(ArrayList value)
{
    _SpillageRiskDescriptions = value;
}
```

Note that by assigning an `ArrayList` instance into your property you basically *replace* the `ArrayList` instance pointed to by the backing field.

To answer your particular questions:

> Therefore am I correct in thinking that properties return a **reference** to the original variable and not passing it by **value**?

No, by using the getter you don't get a reference to the `_SpillageRiskDescriptions` field. You get the *value* of the field which is a reference to a (dynamically allocated) `ArrayList` instance.

> Is this because `ArrayList` is a reference type?

Yes, `ArrayList` is a reference type and thus you receive the reference to the particular `ArrayList` instance.

> Will the same happen with an `int` (for example?)

Yes and no. *Yes*, you will receive the value of an `int` field. And *no*, `int` is a value type, so if you modify the value without explicitly setting it back, the underlying field won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to with the property.

In this case, you are passing a reference to the array list by value.

If you do something like

```
      void AddSomethingToArrayList(ArrayList spillageRiskDescriptions){
           spillageRiskDescriptions.Add("Something");
      }
```

then the reference to the array list will be modified.

If you were to do something like

```
      void ReassignArrayList(ArrayList spillageRiskDescriptions){
           spillageRiskDescriptions = new ArrayList();
           spillageRiskDescriptions.Add("Something");
      }
```

then the original reference to the array list would not be changed at all.

But if you were to pass the reference by reference such as in:

```
      void ReassignArrayListByRef(ref ArrayList spillageRiskDescriptions){
           spillageRiskDescriptions = new ArrayList();
           spillageRiskDescriptions.Add("Something");
      }
```

then your property would end up with a new array list with a single item.