# C#, using ++ operator on value obtained via property (get)

Tags: c#, properties

In C# we define a property as follows:

```
// m_age is a private int in the class Employee
public int Age
{
    get {return m_age;}
    set {m_age = value;}
}
```

Now, when I do

```
static void Main()
{
    Employee e = new Employee(age: 28); // Create new Employee
    System.Console.WriteLine("Age: {0}", e.Age); // Prints 28
    
    // Now increase age by 1
    ++e.Age;

    System.Console.WriteLine("Age: {0}", e.Age); // Prints 29
}
```

Why does the

```
++e.Age;
```

work? I did some searching and found [Properties - by value or by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274752/properties-by-value-or-reference)

This post had an answer:

> Technically it's always by value, but you have to understand what is being passed. Since it's a reference type, you are passing a reference back (but by value).
>
> Hope that makes sense. You always pass the result back by value, but if the type is a reference you are passing the reference back by value, which means you can change the object, but not which object it refers to.

(I do have a good understand of value-types and reference-types, hence my confusion).

Now, if indeed

```
e.Age
```

returns a **copy** of m_age (int is a value-type), won't we apply the increment ++ to the copy?

Or...is the following true?

```
++e.Age;
```

is exactly the same/gets translated to

```
e.Age = e.Age + 1
```

only that

```
++e.Age;
```

returns a value (the value of e.Age after it has been incremented) whereas

```
e.Age = e.Age + 1
```

is an assignment and does not return a value (like C++ would do for example).

Comment: It seems I was wrong about e.Age = e.Age + 1 not returning a value, it does indeed return the value of e.Age after the addition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `++` operator, unless redefined, will `get`, modify and `set` the value again.

A good way to check this is to define the get and set and go through in debug mode. This behavior is also [detailed in the C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#prefix-increment-and-decrement-operators) for increment and decrement operators.

Comment: Note that `++` cannot be redefined on its own in C#. The only way to modify its behavior is by overloading the `+` operator.

Comment: Ok, so I was corrent in my final comments about the equivalence with e.Age = e.Age + 1 ?

Comment: @mikez right, this is important. I'll quote you if you're ok with that

Comment: @jensa yes. A good way to check this is to define the `get` and `set` and go through in debug mode.

Comment: @PhilippeParé Thanks, I'll try that! (I did this code in notepad, will try in VS).

Comment: @jensa The equivalence is correct in this particular example, however `++` always returns a value. Assignments can be expressions as well.

Comment: Here's the part in the spec that describes this behaviour: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691369(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @PhilippeParé Sure quote me, if you want.

Comment: @PhilippeParé Wow, I take it back. Actually you can overload `++` and `--` separately from `+` and `-`. Can't believe I never noticed that before.

Comment: @Giles Thanks, that described it perfectly!